# Wpf Fire an Mouse events(Like MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove, MouseLeftClick) from ItemsControl which has DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, user-controls, mouseevent, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I have Data template which contains a Text box. Data Template is called from Items Control. I want to fire some Mouse events from Text Box which is in Data Template and capture/subscribe that mouse event in View Model which corresponds to the View which has Data template.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by either using EventTriggers in your template or with EventSetters in the templates Style. These can either bind to the codebehind of the file they are declared in or to something else. To get codebehind for a ResourceDictionary simply make a code file with the same name with the extension .xaml.cs and declare it as the Class of the ResourceDictionary in the .xaml file.